# Integration strategy for $\int_0^1(-\ln x)^2dx$

Tags: integration, logarithms, improper-integrals

**Calculus 2**

**Problem**: The region bounded by $y=-lnx$ and the $x$-axis on the interval from $0$ to $1$ is rotated about the $x$-axis. Find the volume if possible

**Thought Process**:

So far, I have the problem setup for using washer/disk method to solve

$$\pi\int_0^1(-\ln x)^2dx$$

I'm not sure how exactly to proceed from here. A simple U-sub from here doesn't help because I have nothing swap for $du$. My next idea would be Integration by Parts setting $u=-lnx$ and $dv=-lnx$, but I don't know what $\int-\ln x$ would be.

I could try shells instead, but that would change my limits of integration, though that might not be a big deal. So...

$$y=-lnx$$

$$x=e^{-y}$$

$$2\pi\int_0^\infty ye^{-y}dy$$

This looks like a decent candidate for parts, so I'll try $u=e^{-y}$ and $dv=y$, resulting in $du=-e^{-y}$ and $dv=ydy$

$$-\frac12e^{-y}y^2-\int_0^\infty \frac12y^2(-e^{-y})dy$$

Which doesn't look any easier than the first one, so maybe Integration by Parts isn't a great idea.

I cant think of how to proceed with either of these.

**Question**:

How can I proceed to find an antiderivative of either

Washer/Disk Method $\pi\int_0^1(-\ln x)^2dx$

Shells Method $2\pi\int_0^\infty ye^{-y}dy$

**Note**: I don't really need help with the Improper Integral portion of this, at least...I don't think I will. I only left the limits of integration on there to show that I know what the problem is asking. I know that I'll need to substitute the discontinuities with a variable and take the limit as the variable approaches the discontinuity and I don't think I'll have a problem with that. I'd really just like some advice on what strategy to use to find the antiderivative for either of these. I can't think of a method that seems like it will work.

Thanks in advance for any advice

**Edit** At the behest of users Babak and Triatticus, I swapped my $u$ and $dv$ choices for the Integration by Parts with the shells method and came to a much friendlier derivative

$u=y$  $dv=e^{-y}dy$

$du=dy$  $v=-e^{-y}$

$2\pi (-ye^{-y}-\int_0^\infty -e^{-y}dy)$

Since this is an Improper Integral, I must take the limit as the function approaches infinity

$$2\pi (-ye^{-y}-\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}[e^{-y}]|_0^t)$$

And since it is integration by parts I need to apply the limits of integration to the $uv$ portion of $uv-\int vdu$ leading to

$$2\pi (-ye^{-y}|_0^\infty-\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}[e^{-y}]|_0^t)$$

and again this is improper so I will replace the $\infty$ with another variable

$$2\pi (\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}-ye^{-y}|_0^m-\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}[e^{-y}]|_0^t)$$

For the sake of completion

$$-2\pi [\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(me^{-m}-0e^-0)+\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(e^{-t}-e^{-0})]$$

**Skip to Edit 2, below is incorrect**

$$-2\pi [\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(me^{-m})+\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(e^{-t})]$$

$$-2\pi [\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(m\frac1{e^{m}})+\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(\frac1{e^{t}})]$$

So, $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(\frac1{e^{t}})$ will become $0$, and $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(m\frac1{e^{m}})$ is an $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so we use L'Hospital's Rule to analyze by comparing the derivative of the numerator to the derivative of the denominator

Numerator:$\frac{d}{dm} m = 1$

Denominator: $\frac{d}{dm} e^m=e^m$

So ultimately, the denominator will approach infinity faster than the numerator, meaning that this is also equal to zero and the final equation becomes

$$-2\pi (0 + 0)$$

And now that I wrote this all out it seems wrong to me because that means that this function has a volume of zero...

The official question was answered long ago but I may need to make another thread to see if anyone would be willing to check my work because a volume of zero doesn't seem right to me

**Edit 2** As I was going through my work again I noticed a problem, $e^{-0}$ does not equal $0$, will update for a last and final (hopefully) time after correcting my work on paper with what should be the correct answer

**Final Edit** This is the answer to the problem as a whole and not just my question, for anyone's future reference. The steps done above are correct except that $e^{-0}=1$ and not zero

$$-2\pi [\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(me^{-m})+\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(e^{-t})-1]$$

$$-2\pi [\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{m}{e^{m}})+\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{1}{e^{t}}-1)]$$

So, $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(\frac1{e^{t}})$ will become $0$, and $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(m\frac1{e^{m}})$ is an $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so we use L'Hospital's Rule to analyze by comparing the derivative of the numerator to the derivative of the denominator

Numerator:$\frac{d}{dm} m = 1$

Denominator: $\frac{d}{dm} e^m=e^m$

Resulting in $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(m\frac1{e^{m}})$ ultimately equaling zero, leaving the following

$$-2\pi [0+0-1)]$$

$$-2\pi [-1]$$

$2\pi$ is the final answer for the volume

Comment: Integration by parts is the right choice, but you should take it as $u=y$ and $\mathrm{d}v=\mathrm{e}^{-x}$.

Comment: Just a note, when integrating by parts in that cylindrical shells method, you make the opposite choice for $u$ and $dv$ that you've made...a handy acronym to look up is LIATE which gives a suggested rule of thumb on the choice of $u$ when confronted with several functions in the integrand. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#LIATE_rule

Comment: Thanks you guys, ill give it a shot and edit after I've done so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

use integration by parts
$$
\int udv=uv-\int vdu
$$
with, for the first integral:
$$
u=\ln^2x \qquad du=\frac{2 \ln x}{x}dx
$$
$$
v=x \qquad dv =dx
$$
and for the second integral:
$$
u=x \qquad du=dx
$$
$$
v=-e^{-x} \qquad dv= e^{-x}dx
$$

Answer (score 1):

Integrate $$\pi\int_{0}^{1}\left(-\ln x\right)^2dx=\pi \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(\int_{0}^{1} x^t dx\right)\bigg|_{t=0}
= \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(\frac\pi{t+1}\right) \bigg|_{t=0} =2\pi
$$